# Riemann Integral on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have the following question.

Find a function $f(x,y)$ that is integrable on rectangle $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, such that $g(y) = f(\frac{1}{2}, y)$ is not integrable for $y \in [0,1]$, or prove that it is impossible.

I think it is not possible. The reason is that if $f$ is integrable on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, then $g$ will be a function over the set $\{(\frac{1}{2}, y) : y \in [0,1]\}$. What I have tried is following.

Let $R = [0,1] \times [0,1]$. Since $f$ is integrable on $R$, there is a partition $P = \{ 0 = x_0, \ldots , x_n = 1 ; 0 = y_0 , \ldots , y_m = 1 \}$ such that the lower Riemann sum $s_Pf$ and the upper Riemann sum $S_Pf$ so that the lower and upper integrals are equal.

I am stuck here and I am not even sure if I am on the right track. I am was thinking that I could prove it if I fix the partition $P$ such that $P = \{ \frac{1}{2} ; 0 = y_0 , \ldots , y_m = 1 \}$ and show that $g$ is integrable using the Cauchy Criterion for integrability.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(\frac{1}{2},y)$ to be the Dirichlet function in $y$ and $f(x,y) = 1$ otherwise. $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ but $g(y) = f(\frac{1}{2},y)$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. $f$ is Riemann integrable on the unit square because the partition of $x$ containing $x = \frac{1}{2}$ can be made arbitrarily small. Since the infimum and supremum of $f$ on $x = \frac{1}{2}$ are bounded, the contribution to the Riemann sum from the partition containing $x = \frac{1}{2}$ can be made arbitrarily small. In essence we can just ignore $x = \frac{1}{2}$ when evaluating the Riemann integral of $f$ over $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Comment: I am going to need more explanation. Also, can we find such function or not?? Is the function you gave is such function $f$??

Comment: I just added an explanation. Hope that helps.

Comment: I am going to look over what the Dirichlet function is but it kind of make sense why $f$ is integrable in this case. But isn't the proof has to be for general function $f$?? Because I think the question asks to find $f$ if there is one otherwise we need to prove for general function $f$. Am I missing something??

Comment: I used the Dirichlet function because that was the first non-Riemann integrable function that came to my mind. As for your other doubt, I found a function $f$ that was Riemann  integrable on $[1,0] \times [1,0]$ but $f(\frac{1}{2},y)$ was not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. The question was asking precisely for this, or to prove such a thing to be impossible. If I were proving that such a thing is impossible, then I would have needed to prove it for a general $f$.

Comment: You can use any nonintegrable, bounded function you want on that line, if you don't want to use the Dirchlet function.